# HDF5 file content disappears after writing process finishes

Tags: python, io, h5py

I'm using `h5py` to iteratively write to a large array with python. It takes quite a long time and I can watch the file size grow as the code is running.

Unfortunately, wenn my python programm exits, the file content disappears. The file is not corrupt, but all values are `0.0` (the fill value I set).
I made sure the file `f` is closed with `f.close()`, and after closing the file (but before exiting the program), the file was still intact and content was there.

Is anyone familiar with this behaviour and can explain what happens there? I'd appreciate any help!

To give you a bit more information, here is what I do specifically. I created a `Process` that processes results from a `Queue`. When the process is initialised, the HDF5 file is created, and when the last item in the queue is reached, the file is closed. All of this seems to work fine (as described above) but I'm mentioning it as I don't have a lot of experience with processes and wondering if the file handling in the process class could be the problem.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
import h5py

class ResultProcessor(Process):

    def __init__(self, result_queue, result_file):
        Process.__init__(self)
        self.result_queue = result_queue
        self.daemon = True

        #open result file handle ('w')
        self.f = h5py.File(result_file, 'w')
        self.dset = self.f.create_dataset('zipped', (num_jobs, num_subjects), compression="gzip", fillvalue=0)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            next_result = self.result_queue.get()

            if next_result is None:
                # Poison pill means we should exit
                self.f.close()
                return

            idx, result = next_result
            self.dset[idx,:] = result
```

The process is then initialised and run as below:

```
# results_queue is still empty
result_processor = ResultProcessor(results_queue, file_name)
result_processor.start()

# now the result queue is filled
process_stuff_and_feed_to_result_queue()
# add last queue item so the end can be recognised:
result_queue.put(None)

result_processor.join()

# I checked at this point: The file content is still around!
```

Comment: The only issue I could think of is that the __init__ method of the Process is executed in main thread. Maybe move the opening of the hdf5 file to the beginning of the run method??

Answer (score 0):

While this won't solve why the contents of the file appears to disappear, you should keep in mind that HDF5 (and hence h5py) is not designed to write to have multiple programs (using multiprocessing usually falls under this) writing to the same file. There is MPI support and SWMR (single writer multiple reader) in 1.10, but you don't have complete freedom to write anything in any order.