# Opening file in __init__ function problematic?

Tags: python, process, io, multiprocessing, terminate

I wrote a sub-class of `multiprocessing.Process` and opened a write-access file handle in the `__init__` function (as also described in an [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36808962/2323484)):

```
class ProcessChild(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self, file_name):
        Process.__init__(self)
        self.f = open(file_name, 'w')

    def run():
        while True:
            # write to file.
            # when done, close file.
            # break
```

I noticed that the file is erased during the termination of my python script. The only explanation I have is that the `__init__` function is called again during termination, causing the existing file `file_name` to be overwritten with a new empty file. If I open the file at the start of the `run()` function instead, everything works fine.

Can someone explain what exactly happens when a script using `Processes` terminates?

Comment: I posted this as a separate question as this time, the focus is on the termination of python scripts instead of HDF5. I might delete the other question in a bit, when I'm sure this is the cause (and solution) of my problem.

Comment: If your hypothesis is correct changing the mode `'w'` to `'a'` would not erase the file. Did you try that?  Otherwise it's probably a flushing issue (so you aren't actually closing/flushing the file properly). Without the actual code you use we cannot tell whether it's possible for the file to fail to close/flush the writes...

Comment: I considered this, but I actually want the file to be erased when I first initialise the process. My code is slightly more convoluted, but I double-checked (i.e. printed the file status) that the file handles are closed properly. However, apart from solving the issue (which I did, by opening the file in `run`), I'm mostly interested in why these variables would be re-initialised when my script terminates.